# Object A properties change through Object B properties as references

Tags: c#, .net, oop

Lets say I have object A which properties I want to assign to Object B and by modifying object B I'd like Object A reference type properties to change also. Objects are not the same.

```
Class A 
{
   public string Link1 { get; set;}
}

Class B 
{        
   public string Link { get; set;}
}

public void ProcessLink(ref B b)
{
    b.Link = serviceX.GetLink(); // this should set Obj A.Link value too
}
```

How code should look like? so that Objects A property Link1 would be updated by calling

```
var a = new A(){ Link1 = null};
var b = new B() {Link = a.Link1};
ProcessLink(ref B);
```

now a.Link1 is equal to b.Link

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @serge how to change obj A property through object B, which does not have the same property name in its parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're describing `B` being a *proxy* for `A`. One way to do this would be to give class `B` a reference to an instance of `A`. Instead of auto-properties, write getters and setters for `B` that actually operate on the `A`. You could give `A` a method to obtain an instance of `B`.

An example of this pattern is `CancellationTokenSource` (analogous to `A`) and `CancellationToken` (`B`). The tokens are proxies that expose the cancelled property of the source, but don't let you cancel it.

Consider whether it makes more sense to make `B` an interface that `A` implements.

Comment: Interfaces would be easy, but a and b are Different objects with only some sared properties...